# Meaning of quotient torus in abelian manifold case

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian manifold. Let $T$ be an abelian manifold and complex torus. Suppose $A\to T$ is surjective holomorphic homomorphism of abelian manifold.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Do I need $T$ to be an abelian variety to start with? What is the meaning of quotient torus in $A\to T$ sense here? Since $A$ is isogenous to $T\times T'$ where $T'$ is another abelian manifold, do I call $T$ quotient? Since isogeny says there is still a finite kernel, I cannot really say $\frac{A}{T'}\cong T$ in any sense.(Normally I would expect quotient as normal quotient in group.) What is the meaning of the quotient torus?

Comment: I would guess that quotient simply means quotient both as a topological space as well as an abelian group. So the inverse image of the identity is a closed subgroup and all other inverse images are translations of this subgroup by a point. I don't know the subject well so this might be wrong...

Comment: @ArithmeticGeometer If it is quotient of abelian group, then I could define exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to Ker(A\to T)\to A\to T\to 0$. The question is whether $Ker(A\to T)$ necessarily a torus? From isogeny, $A$ is upto a finite kernel similar to $T\times T'$. In other words, $T'$ mod out that extra kernel part has to be a torus. I doubt this will be the case in general.

Comment: I don't believe the kernel needs to be a torus. Consider $z \to z^n$ for $A = T$ one dimensional ( $= \mathbb C^\times)$. Then the map is surjective and the kernel is a discrete subgroup.

Comment: @ArithmeticGeometer: the OP probably means that $A$ is a **connected compact**  holomorphic group. The word *torus* has unfortunately two incompatible meanings: the one I just defined or a product $(\mathbb C^*)^n$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Swinnerton-dyer used $A$ is a quotient of $C^n$ by a rank $2n$ lattice. $A$ is a complex manifold which is automatically connected compact. Would you mind clarify what is the difference between two definitions when it comes to quotient torus and subtorus? Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Swinnerton-Dyer's definition. I was answering @ArithmeticGeometer who considered that $\mathbb C^\times$ is a torus in the first line of his second comment. Your first line is a bit unclear : it is true that all abelian varieties are complex tori (in the sense of Swinnerton-Dyer) but the converse is false.  An abelian variety is an **algebraic** torus and most complex tori are not abelian varieties, i.e. are not algebraic.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes. You are right. Generic lattice does not admit a positive definite hermitian form which gives projective embedding. I think I assumed that the torus admits a projective embedding by a non-degenerate positive divisor.